# display output from .java in .jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, ftp

I have a java file that is connecting to an ftp server and bringing back a list of directories from the server. My question is what is the proper method of grabbing the list from the java file and displaying the results of the directories in my jsp?

Would you suggest I connect to the ftp server straight from the jsp or is this bad coding practices?

example:

Connect.java

```
package root;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;


public class ConnectFTP {


private void showServerReply(FTPClient ftpClient) {
    String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
    if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
        for (String aReply : replies) {
            System.out.println("SERVER: " + aReply);
        }
    }
}



public void listFTPVendors(String[] args) {
    String server = "ftpserver.com";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "username";
    String pass = "password";
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        showServerReply(ftpClient);
        int replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();C
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
            System.out.println("Operation failed. Server reply code: " + replyCode);
            return;
        }
        boolean success = ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        showServerReply(ftpClient);
        if (!success) {
            System.out.println("Could not login to the server");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("LOGGED IN SERVER");
        }
        FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listDirectories();
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            String details = file.getName();
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                details = "[" + details + "]";
            }
            System.out.println(details);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Oops! Something wrong happened");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}

}
```

Connect.jsp

??

I'm merely looking for suggestions not necessarily code. Maybe even some reading material. Fairly new and lost...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating through `files` and printing it, do `return files` and change the return type of the method `listFTPVendors(String[] args)` to `FTPFile[]`.

Now, call this method from your `JSP` and retrieve data in `JSP` code.

```
<%FTPFile[] files = new ConnectFTP().listFTPVendors()%>
```

Don't forget to import the class `ConnectFTP` in your `JSP`.

Iterate through `files` in `JSP` and show it on webpage.

Comment: how might that look with what i have?

Comment: Just the minor changes which I mentioned in answer.

Comment: What should args evaluate to then in the jsp?

Comment: You don't use the "args" parameter in your method... just remove it!  It should be public void listFTPVendors() {...}

Comment: Exactly, `args` is not even used inside the method.

Comment: using your code @ShrinivasShukla I'm getting The method listFTPVendors() is undefined for the type 
 __2F_DataTransformationSite_2F_WebContent_2F_Incoming_2E_jsp

Comment: Got you...Should I iterate through the files using jstl or is there a better way?

Comment: Iterating using `JSTL` is preferred over for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JSP is for presentation logic so it will be better if you keep your networking code in separate Java file :)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using the Apache Commons FTP api. You are pretty much doing it correctly.

I also believe that you are unnecessarily testing for a directory when your collection is only made up of directories.
This is because you are using the listDirectories() method.
If you called the listFiles() then you would have to test each file is a directory, as you have done.

You should be able modify your code as follows:

```
...
FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listDirectories();
for (FTPFile file : files) {
    System.out.println("["+ file.getName() +"]");
}
...
```

As far as connecting to the FTP server directly from your JSP page - there is nothing 'wrong' there, but usually the jsp's are used for display purposes.

I would avoid hard coding the credentials in the page - they should be externalized into a config file.  The config file should also be stored in a location that cannot be accessed via the browser.

Depending on what web framework you are using - you may want to wrap this functionality into a controller or service.